# How to make my EC2 instance storage increase automatically

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, amazon-ebs

I'm running an AWS ec2 instance for managing CPE devices.
It used to be 8G but I increased it to 150G and I keep needing more. How can I automate it so I don't have to modify my EBS storage and expand the file system manually using AWS services? Should I use AWS CloudWatch with Lambda? What are the steps to implement a task for this purpose?

What is the most cost-efficient way?

I manually update it every time. I also tried to implement it with services but I couldn't figure out how. Can you give me steps on how to do that?
What is the best architecture to have a reliable and optimized server?

I tried using [Automating Amazon EBS volume resizing with AWS Step Functions and AWS Systems Manager | AWS Storage Blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/storage/automating-amazon-ebs-volume-resizing-with-aws-step-functions-and-aws-systems-manager/) but it didn't help much.

Comment: What volumes are involved? For example, what is the current size of the EBS volume and how much did you increase it recently? What are you storing on the EBS volume -- it might be that we can suggest a more appropriate storage service for the data (eg Amazon S3). Please Edit your question to provide this additional information.

Comment: Only on the ec2 instance can you determine free space (not visible from the hypervisor) or resize the filesystem (and partition if it has one).  So your solution could be as simple as having a cron check free space every few minutes and call ModifyVolume / resize fs command.  I'd recommend against resizing the root filesystem - dedicate a volume to the high use purpose - and don't partition it, it's pointless and handling partition table is  the most complex step in the process.  You can add an ec2 role to the instance to grant it ModifyVolume permissions.

Comment: You may want to consider using a service for your storage needs. For example EFS or FSx for NetApp ONTAP. Both have auto grow features.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I use it to manage and monitor CPE devices. What do you think i should do?

Comment: How do you use the data stored on the EBS volume? Is _ALL_ of it needed all of the time? You can always copy it off to an Amazon S3 bucket, but it will not be the same as having it on the local disk. It really depends on how much of the data you actually need at any time and how 'easily' it should be accessible. Plus, data stored on S3 is accessible to other instances and applications so it might be better depending upon your use-case. Or, just create a big EBS volume that should cater for your future needs. You'll be paying for the big size immediately, but you won't need to resize.